# Uipath queue items oldest first

Tags: uipath

Is there a way of setting uipath to get the oldest queue items first and work them before the newer ones? I.e. The oldest created date to be worked first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queues are processed based on priority, and afterwards creation time. Priority is defined by priority level(low, normal, high) and starting with 2016.2 by due date and defer date fields

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table extracted for it that you can sort the cases on the basis of time each time and take the first case.
Alternatively, You can set the sequence or the flow by increasing or decreasing order as per the data and execute.